# scanf format string not recognized

Tags: c, input, buffer, scanf, stdin

I' ve inserted the followings input for the follow program:

```
a b c d e
```

After the e letter I've pressed Enter, but the program blocks on scanf for i equal to 3.
Seems that scanf is not able to  fetch other character from stdin.
Thanks in advance for your help.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {
        char a[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            scanf("%c ", a + i);
            printf("i = %d a[%d] = %c \n", i, i, a[i]);
        }

        int i = 0;
        while( i < 5 )
        {
            printf("%c ", a[i]);
            i++;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't block when i == 3 -- it completes that iteration -- it blocks when i == 4.

That's because of the space after the `%c` in the scanf format -- a space causes scanf to read input and skip whitespace up until it finds a non-whitespace character.  That non-whitespace character will then be left in the FILE input buffer as the next character to be read.  So in the 5th iteration of the loop (i == 4), it reads the `e` then reads whitespace looking for non-whitespace.  So the newline is skipped over (it's whitespace) and it starts (trying to) read the next line which blocks.

Once you provide the next line (assuming its not empty/all whitespace), it will get a non-whitespace character and `scanf` will return.

Answer (score -2):

Using scanf to fetch a single character at a time from stdin is not a good idea. If the user types more than one character, you can overflow the buffer as there is no room for the null character. This also leaves excess characters in stdin.

Another idea is to use a special format string flag to fetch 5 characters at once, and then print them or do whatever you want with them.

You can use the flag `"%5c"`, where 5 is any integer number, that reads, *scan exactly 5 characters*.

Here is the modified version of your code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char a[5];
    scanf("%5c", a);

    int i = 0;
    while( i < 5 )
    {
        printf("%c ", a[i]);
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now there is no blocking.

Comment: this is wrong and overflows the buffer because you need room for nul termination of the string

Comment: I meant to say that it leaves unused characters in stdin, i will edit.

Comment: This won't work.  `%s` in scanf will terminate on the first white space. So, only the character a will be read into the array.

Comment: Changing it to %5c, which works across white space character.

Comment: @JoshWeinstein I don't think that would work either since the spaces will be read into the array as well. So, if the user types in `a b c d e`, then the 5 slots in the array a will end up holding these 5 characters: `a b c`.